# jquery count elements with attribute

Tags: jquery, count

Can I count the number of elements with a specific attribute?

For example all the images with the src attribute test.gif

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the CSS **[attribute selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue)** to filter on the attribute

```
$("img[src='test.gif']").length;
```

the **[size()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/size)** and **[length](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/length)** both returns the number of elements matched;

Answer (score 6):

if you want to check the presence of the attribute only

```
$('img[src]').length //or .size()
```

Answer (score 3):

You want size() so something like:

something like:

```
$('img[src="test.gif"]').size();
```

Comment: `.length` is preferred because it is an attribute vs. a function call. In large loops, `length` will perform better.