# Count number of li elements with certain css

Tags: jquery, count, html-lists, element

I'm trying to count a number of li elements with the css attribute of "display:block" and I can't get it right.
I used this great question and answers: [jquery count elements with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030691/jquery-count-elements-with-attribute)

And it works, but not with li for some reason.
Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
     alert($("li[display='block']").length);
});
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dQTgg/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try that:

```
$(function() {
    alert($("li[style='display:block']").length);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQTgg/1/)

If there are some additional CSS rules then use that:

```
$(function() {
    var el = $('li').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('display') == 'block';
    });
    alert(el.length);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQTgg/4/)

Comment: Wow great!
It's that simple... Thanks!

Comment: This will return incorrect value if there are additional css rules on `li` elements. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dQTgg/3/)

Answer (score 5):

A more proper way to check for `li`s with display = 'block' will be

```
$('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('display') == 'block'
}).length
```

but if you want to count visible `li`s then you can use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
$('li:visible').length
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    alert($("li:visible").length);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dQTgg/2/)

```
$(function() {
    var count=0;
    $("li").each(function(){
        if($(this).css('display') == 'block'){
            count++;
        }
    });
    alert(count);
});
```