# Counting the number of times a <label> element appears in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the help of jquery I am able to dynamically add/remove input fields. But I am having difficulties trying to count the number of labels `data-bind='personCount'` and display in the html the result. For example for every item show `Person #1, Person #2, Person #3`, etc. I have been able to get this working with `items` in select dropdown menu. How can I count the number of time the labels `data-bind='personCount', to show`Person #1`, etc.?  Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6MXrN/1/)

Jquery

```
var template;

function Person() { //we use this as an object constructor.
    this.personCount= 0;
    this.firstName = '';
}

function renderItem() {
    template = template || $("[data-template=item]").html();
    var el = $("<div></div>").html(template);
    return el; // a new element with the template
}

function addItem() {
    var person = new Person(); // get the data
    var el = renderItem(); // get the element

    el.find("[data-bind=personCount]").keyup(function (e) {

    });

    el.find("[data-bind=firstName]").keyup(function (e) {
        person.firstName = this.value;
    });

    return {
        el: el,
        person: person
    }
}

var stuff = [];
$("[data-action='add']").click(function(e){
     var item = addItem();
     $("body").append(item.el);
     stuff.push(item);
});

$("[data-action='remove']").click(function(e){
      if(stuff.length > 1) {
          var item = stuff.pop()
          item.el.remove();
      }
});

     var item = addItem();
     $("body").append(item.el);
     stuff.push(item);


  });
```

HTML

```
<div>
<script type='text/template' data-template='item'>
<ul class="clonedSection">
<label data-bind='personCount' class="personCount">Person # {person_count}</label> 
    <li style="list-style-type: none;">
        <input type="text" data-bind='firstName' placeholder="First Name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
    </li>
</ul>
</script>
<input type='button' value='add' data-action='add' />
<input type='button' value='remove' data-action='remove' />
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery count elements with attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030691/jquery-count-elements-with-attribute)

Comment: But you could also just keep a running index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write:

```
var count = $("body").find(".personCount[data-bind='personCount']").length;
$("body").find(".personCount[data-bind='personCount']:last").text("Person # {"+count+"}");
```

`$("body").find(".personCount[data-bind='personCount']").length` will give you number of elements having class `personCount` and attribute `data-bind='personCount'`.

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6MXrN/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update to your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/6MXrN/4/

I think this is what you're looking for. I just did

```
$('label[data-bind="currentPerson"]).length
```

to get the number of your label elements.